# Hostbinding ngIf in Angular2

Tags: angular

Consider this Child Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'mySelector',
    template: `<ion-spinner [ngIf]="ngif"></ion-spinner>`
})


export class MyDirective {

    ngif: boolean;
    constructor() {}

    @Input() serverWaiting:boolean = true;
    @HostBinding('ngIf')

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.ngif = !this.serverWaiting ? true : null;
    }
```

The Host Component's Template:

```
 <mySelector [serverWaiting]></mySelector>
```

The Host Component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'hostComp.html',
    directives: [myDirective]
})

export class HostComp {
    serverWaiting = true;
}
```

Yet, the Spinner is not shown. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Sources: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@HostBinding('ngIf')` decorator needs to be before the property with the value that should be bound.

```
export class MyDirective {
    constructor() {}

    @HostBinding('ngIf')
    ngif: boolean;

    @Input() serverWaiting:boolean = true;

    ngOnChanges() {
        this.ngif = !this.serverWaiting ? true : null;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't look valid

```
<mySelector [serverWaiting]></mySelector>
```

`[serverWaiting]` indicates property binding but doesn't bind a value. This doesn't assign `true` in case you expect that. You would need

```
<mySelector [serverWaiting]="true"></mySelector>
```

Comment: When using `[ngIf]="ngIf"`, I am getting a `myDirective - inline template:3:12
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for TemplateRef!`. Using `*ngIf` gets rid of the error, but still the spinner is shown all the time.

Comment: That's probably because naming a property `ngIf` is a bad idea. Please use some different name instead.

Comment: Hi.. works now even with naming the directive instance member `ngIf`. Problem was negation before `this.serverWaiting`, such works: `this.ngif = this.serverWaiting ? true : null;`.