# Angular 2 - apply ngIf on host element using @HostBinding

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set ngIf on the host element using @HostBinding decorator.

```
class ListItem {
    @HostBinding('ngIf') active: boolean = false;
}
```

And I'm getting the error: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'list-item'.

However I see an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38691703/1267778) which seems to be suggesting this usage.

Comment: I didn't think of this use case when I answered the question :D, but that's won't work for the `ngIf` directive (see my answer).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ngIf` is a directive and directives can't be added dynamically. They are only applied if markup added statically to a components template matches the selector.

`@HostBinding()` only supports `class.`, `attr.`, and `style.` bindings.

Answer (score 3):

just wrap youur template in `<ng-container *ngIf="active"></ng-container>` instead of using host binding