# Using HostListener/Binding with a NgFor Element in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, ngfor, angular2-hostbinding

I have list of users. I want that when the cursor hover on the button, it sets `*ngIf` to true and then displays information about the user (and false when the cursor leave the button).

**`user-list.html`:**

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
  <h1>{{user.name}}</h1>
  <div onUserHover *ngIf="ngIf">
    <p>{{user.description}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**`user-list.component.ts`:**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from 'class/user';
import { UserService } from 'user/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-list',
  templateUrl: 'user-list.component.html',
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];
  
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().then(users => this.users = users);
  }
    
  toggleUser(user: User): void {
    user.active = !user.active;
  }
}
```

I used "toggleUser(user: User)" like this :
`(click)='toggleUser(user)'`, however I want now a `onHover` instead of click.

I saw the tutorial about directives attributes on Angular.io website and a StackOverflow topic on `HostBinding('ngIf')`.

[Hostbinding ngIf in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688027/hostbinding-ngif-in-angular2)

**`onUserHover.directive.ts`:**

```ts
 import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[onUserHover]' })
export class OnUserHoverDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostBinding('ngIf') ngIf: boolean;

    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
        console.log('onMouseEnter');
        this.ngIf = true;
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') onmouseleave() {
        this.ngIf = false;
    }
}
```

**But I have one error on the browser :**

```
Can't bind to `ngIf` since it isn't a known property of `div`
```

What can I do to implement this feature in Angular 2 style ?

Comment: You can simply do it with css , then why are you making things so complex ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi I would prefer to do this in code as well, preventing CSS rules. Easier debugging.

Comment: You probably have an issue with the `this` binding, referring to the HTML element instead of your class. Try to bind the function to your class instead.

Comment: that does not make sense at all. You cannot access the parent ngIf from your directive, plus, you would like to append the content when it is hovered and removed when mouse leaves. How do you want to hover a non-existing element ?

Comment: @n00dl3 If you look closely, you see that the `ngIf` is actually a very poorly named boolean and not the Angular `ngIf` module.

Comment: he cannot access the ngIf of the parent: `*ngIf="ngIf"`

Comment: @n00dl3 Is that because it is a reserved keyword? He does declare it in his file as `@HostBinding('ngIf') ngIf: boolean;`

Comment: you cannot modify parent component variables except if it is explicitly specified with a banana in a box binding like `[(ngModel)]` and using an `EventEmitter` in the child... However, hovering a non-existing element is a mystery to me...

Answer (score 0):

What you forgot is to bind the variable to the element

```
<div onUserHover [ngIf]="ngif" *ngIf="ngIf">
```

> ## [Your directive isn't working?](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#apply-the-attribute-directive)
>
> Did you remember to add the directive to the declarations attribute of
>   @NgModule? It is easy to forget! Open the console in the browser tools
>   and look for an error like this:
>
> EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:   Can't bind to 'myHighlight' since
>   it isn't a known property of 'p'.
>
> Angular detects that you're trying to bind to something but it can't
>   find this directive in the module's declarations array. After
>   specifying HighlightDirective in the declarations array, Angular knows
>   it can apply the directive to components declared in this module.

Comment: `@Input('ngIf') ngIf: boolean;`

Comment: Instead of HostBinding in .directive ?

Comment: I did  @HostBinding('ngIf') @Input() ngIf: boolean; in .directive. However it still a known property

Comment: Can you finish the phrase *However it still a known property*?

Comment: Browser still shows me the same error
"Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of <div>
 [ERROR ->]<div onUserHover [ngIf]="ngIf" *ngIf="ngIf">

Comment: This is because you don't have a variable `ngIf` in the component. I also doubt that you can use both directives on the same `div`.